# sccm 2012 sp1, how to let pc join the sccm pool?

Tags: sccm

I have problem in letting pc join the sccm pool.
Somehow our coumputer cannot be staged by sccm, and it needs to be pushing software by the sccm 2012 sp1, So could some one let me know how to let pc join sccm pool? Cuz I have used a cmd-line before, or can it be joined by sccm server interface?
Thanks.

Luke

Answer (score 1):

You need an SCCM client installed on a computer in order to push software to it.

Is this PC a member of the domain?  If it is, then you can enable System Discovery in SCCM to allow SCCM to pull information from AD.  Once this is done, you can go to Assets, Devices and search for your computer.

Right-click it and choose Install Client to push the SCCM Client to this machine.

If remote client push isn't working, then from the system you want to manage, connect to \SCCMServerName\SMS_SITE\Client and run the SCCM Client installer found here.

Once the client is installed, you should be able to push software to this machine.

Answer (score 0):

The following table lists the various methods that you can use to install the Configuration Manager client software on computers.

1. Client push installation
2. Software update point installation
3. Group Policy installation
4. Logon script installation
5. Manual installation
6. Upgrade installation by using application management
7. Automatic client upgrade
8. Client imaging

For a complete description of the steps mentioned above, check out this article:
[How to Install Clients on Windows-Based Computers in Configuration Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712298.aspx)

One more question, have you extended the Active Directory Schema for Configuration Manager?
[Determine Whether to Extend the Active Directory Schema for Configuration Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712272.aspx)

A little deeper:[ConfigMgr Client Installation Troubleshooting Check List](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6799.configmgr-client-installation-troubleshooting-check-list.aspx)